# How to search multiple keywords in file using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, fs

Lets say i have multiple search keywords from client side `searchStr` that should match with the line in file , how i will match both `text` with each line in file and push that line to `results`. With below code i am getting empty response of `results`, Any idea what is implemented wrong ?

search.js

```
  function asyncFiles(filesData) {
     async.eachSeries(filesData.logFiles, function(logfile, done) {
         // read file
         readStream = fs.createReadStream('./logs/' + filesData.searchEnv + '/' + logfile.filename, 'utf8')
         readStream.pipe(split())
             .on('data', function(line) {
               var searchStr = [{"text":"4588769"},{"text":"request"}]
                 searchStr.forEach(function(text) {
                     if (line.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) != -1)
                         var messageDateInfo = line.split('|')[0].replace(/[\[\]']+/g, '');
                     messageDateInfo = new Date(messageDateInfo).getTime();
                     searchStartDate = new Date(searchStartDate).getTime();
                     searchEndDate = new Date(searchEndDate).getTime();
                     if (messageDateInfo - searchStartDate > 0 && searchEndDate - messageDateInfo > 0) {
                         results.push({
                             filename: logfile.filename,
                             value: line
                         });
                     }
                 });
             });
         done();
     }, function(err) {
         if (err) {
             console.log('error', err);
         }
         readStream.on('end', function() {
             callback(results);
         });
         results = [];
     });
 }
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have?

Comment: i am getting an empty respone its not pusing to `results`

Comment: You are not show what you do with `results`. Could the issue rather be that be that streams are asynchronous but you are trying to use `results` synchronously? Please update your question with the actual problem you are experiencing and a more complete example.

Comment: @FelixKling  thanks , i have updated my question to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

your question does not clearly show what happend with `results` but this code should return certain value of `results` without any dependence:

`function asyncFiles(filesData) {
     async.eachSeries(filesData.logFiles, function(logfile, done) {
         // read file
         readStream = fs.createReadStream('./logs/' + filesData.searchEnv + '/' + logfile.filename, 'utf8')
         readStream.pipe(split())
             .on('data', function(line) {
               var searchStr = [{"text":"4588769"},{"text":"request"}]
                 searchStr.forEach(function(text) {
                     if (line.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) != -1)
                         var messageDateInfo = line.split('|')[0].replace(/[\[\]']+/g, '');
                     messageDateInfo = new Date(messageDateInfo).getTime();
                     searchStartDate = new Date(searchStartDate).getTime();
                     searchEndDate = new Date(searchEndDate).getTime();
                     if (messageDateInfo - searchStartDate > 0 && searchEndDate - messageDateInfo > 0) {
                         results.push({
                             filename: logfile.filename,
                             value: line
                         });
                     }
                 });
             });
         done();
     }, function(err) {
         if (err) {
             console.log('error', err);
         }
         readStream.on('end', function() {
             setTimeout(function(){callback(results);},2000) 
           });
           //results = [];
        });
    }`

Comment: it looks like similar code what did you change except comment out `results`

Answer (score 0):

You can mix slow functions with arbitrary logic and execute it sequentially via synchronous JS executor [nsynjs](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs). Your code will transform as follows:

```
function process(textFile,filesData) {
    var results=[];
    for(var i=0; i<filesData.logFiles.length, i++ ) {
        var file = filesData.logFiles[i];
        var fh = new textFile();
        fh.open(file);
        var line;
        var searchStr = [{"text":"4588769"},{"text":"request"}]
        while (typeof(line = fh.readLine(nsynjsCtx).data) != 'undefined') {
            for(var i=0; i<searchStr.length; i++)
                if (line.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchStr[i].toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                    var messageDateInfo = line.split('|')[0].replace(new RegExp("[\[\]']+","g"), '');
                    messageDateInfo = new Date(messageDateInfo).getTime();
                    searchStartDate = new Date(searchStartDate).getTime();
                    searchEndDate = new Date(searchEndDate).getTime();
                    if (messageDateInfo - searchStartDate > 0 && searchEndDate - messageDateInfo > 0) {
                        results.push({
                            filename: logfile.filename,
                            value: line
                        });
                    };              
                };
        };
        fh.close();
    };
    return results;
};
```

And you can run it via nsynjs like this:

```
var nsynjs = require('nsynjs');
var textFile = require('../../wrappers/nodeReadline').textFile; // part of nsynjs package

function process(...){
...
}

nsynjs.run(process,{},textFile,filesData,function (results) {
    console.log('done', results); // results are ready here
});
```